# Cron job running out of memory very fast

Tags: php, cron

I am hosted on godaddy shared hosting.  My database has over 500 entries, but I expect it to be much higher as time go on.  Maybe in the thousands.  I have this running as a cron job, but it runs out of memory (64 megs) after only 33 records.  I can not change the max memory since I am on shared hosting.  Is there anything I can do to reduce the memory usage?  Perhaps any way to clear the memory each time it loops?

```
include('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = new simple_html_dom();  

$price_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM prices");
while ($price_rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($price_query))
{
$vendor_id = $price_rows['vendor_id'];
$product_id = $price_rows['product_id'];
$product_page = $price_rows['product_page'];
$product_string = $price_rows['product_string'];
$product_array = $price_rows['product_array'];

if (urlOK($product_page))
    {
    $html = file_get_html($product_page);  

    $new_price = $html->find($product_string); 
    $new_price = preg_replace('/[\$,]/', '', $new_price);
    $product_price = $new_price[$product_array];
    $product_price = strip_tags($product_price);

    $qry="UPDATE prices SET product_price='$product_price' WHERE product_id = '$product_id' AND vendor_id = '$vendor_id'";
    mysql_query($qry);
    }

else
    {
    $qry="UPDATE prices SET product_price='0.00' WHERE product_id = '$product_id' AND vendor_id = '$vendor_id'";
    mysql_query($qry);
    }

$vendor_id = null;
$product_id = null;
$product_page = null;
    $product_string = null;
    $product_array = null;
$qry = null;
$html = null;
}
```

This is the 1 function im calling:

```
function urlOk($url) 
{
    $headers = @get_headers($url);
    if($headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK') return true;
    else return false;
}
```

Comment: Yes, use `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` in your query. At present you are trying to load all records into memory in one go - load them in blocks and it will be _much_ more memory-efficient.

Comment: @halfer What's the benefit of doing so? I don't see a memory leak here. I would profile the script using `xdebug`

Comment: He's only reading one row at a time with `mysql_fetch_assoc()`, he's not reading the whole result into memory.

Comment: @halfer He is using a `fetch_assoc` within a loop - thus bringing back one row at a time and then progressing to the next one. Using a limit will do nothing here.

Comment: I thought I was only working with 1 row at a time.  After 33 loops through this though I exceed 64 megs of memory.  No matter what I change it always fails after 33 records.

Comment: You are updating the database while looping through it. I wonder if you could collect all the query strings in an array, and not do any updating until you have collected them all. I am normally very wary of updating objects while I iterate over them. Strange things tend to happen. This is just a hunch though.

Comment: @Katp00p The database code looks ok for me. Do you know how to profile a script using `xdebug`?

Comment: Nope... this website is my way of learning programming.  I learn better by figuring out everything on my own.  I'll go read up on it though.

Comment: @Floris AFAIK At the moment you got a cursor returned from a query the table can be updated while iterating over the cursor. you don't need to worry about that. mysqld will do the job (beat me if I'm wrong, I'm not 100% sure)

Comment: Is there anyway to just unload the memory at the end of each loop?  I thought that is what I was doing setting everything to null but it does not seem to work.

Comment: I think you are forgetting a mysql_free_result($qry); in your loop. I thought you didn't need it for an update because there is no result set but you can try it. And look into using mysqli instead of mysql which is deprecated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK I have figured this out after some hours of research.  The problem itself is in the simple_html_dom library.  There is a massive memory leak if used in a loop.  To fix just add this to the end of the loop:

```
$html->clear();
unset($html);
```